# Stuck messages in azure storage queue

Tags: azure, .net-core

I am using azure storage queue and have a .net core console application, which is continuously polling on this queue and picking the messages to process them.
Below is the code reference to have the queue client created, If you see the logger information here, after completion of this method, again I am getting logs with **Config service call to be started**, which tells, this method is called recursively or in loop, while there is no such code written to call this function.

This is causing other messages stuck in azure queue.

```
     // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetValue<string>("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        _clientProfileQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(_dataConfiguration.ClientProfileQueueName);
        _clientProfileQueue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


private async Task StartClientProfileQueueProcessing()
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                CloudQueueMessage message = await _clientProfileQueue.GetMessageAsync();
                if (message != null)
                {
                    await ProcessClientProfileQueueMessages(message.AsString);
                    await _clientProfileQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               //Logging Exception
            }

            await Task.Delay(RequestProcessingDelayTime);

        } while (true);

    }

public async Task ProcessClientProfileQueueMessages(string message)
    {
        var clientProfileMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceModel.ClientProfile.ClientProfileProperties>(message);
        try
        {
            await SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync(clientProfileMessage);
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                               //Logging Exception
        }
    }

private async Task SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync(ClientProfileProperties msg, bool isSegmentCalculationReq = false)
    {
        var userUid = msg.UserUid.ToString();

        _recommendationLogger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LogEntity()
        {

            Class = "UserProcess",
            Function = "SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync",
            Message = "Config service call to be started",
            LineNumber = UtilityClass.GetLineNumber(),
            Queue = "clientprofilequeue",
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        }));

        var context = new EnricherContextClientSide()
        {
            UserId = userUid,
            IsUserInternational = ProcessFactory.GetProcess<IConfigServiceProcess>().IsUserInstanceIntl(msg.PortalCd),
            UserEvent = new ClientEvent()
        };

        _recommendationLogger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LogEntity()
        {

            Class = "UserProcess",
            Function = "SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync",
            Message = "Config service call ended. IsUserInternational: " + context.IsUserInternational.ToString() + ".",
            LineNumber = UtilityClass.GetLineNumber(),
            Queue = "clientprofilequeue",
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        }));


        var clientProfileDetailsDoc = new ConcurrentBag<ProfileProperty>();
        var clientProfileDetailsEmpData = new ConcurrentBag<ProfileProperty>();
        var clientProfileDetailsEmpSt = new ConcurrentBag<ProfileProperty>();
        var clientProfileDetailsQuestion = new ConcurrentBag<ProfileProperty>();

        foreach(var msgProperty in msg.ClientProfileDetails)
        {
            string section;
            var msgProp = new ProfileProperty() { Key = msgProperty.Key, Value = msgProperty.Value };
            UtilityClass.PropertyCategory.TryGetValue(msgProperty.Key, out section);
            switch (section)
            {
                case PropertyTypeConst.EmploymentStatus:
                    clientProfileDetailsEmpSt.Add(msgProp);
                    break;
                case PropertyTypeConst.EmploymentData:
                    clientProfileDetailsEmpData.Add(msgProp);
                    break;
                case PropertyTypeConst.Document:
                    clientProfileDetailsDoc.Add(msgProp);
                    break;
                case PropertyTypeConst.Questionnaire:
                    clientProfileDetailsQuestion.Add(msgProp);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        _recommendationLogger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LogEntity()
        {

            Class = "UserProcess",
            Function = "SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync",
            Message = "Properties added to concurrent lists.",
            LineNumber = UtilityClass.GetLineNumber(),
            Queue = "clientprofilequeue",
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
        }));

        if (clientProfileDetailsEmpSt.Count > 0 || clientProfileDetailsEmpData.Count > 0 ||
             clientProfileDetailsDoc.Count > 0 || clientProfileDetailsQuestion.Count > 0)
        {
            var userExist = await DataFactory.GetData<IUserData>().CheckKeyExistsAsync(userUid, ClientSource);
            bool result;

            context.UserDataExist = true;
            context.UserEvent.ClientProfileMessage = new ClientProfileMessage
            {
                PortalCd = msg.PortalCd,
                UserUid = msg.UserUid,
                VisitUid = msg.VisitUid,
                VisitorUid = msg.VisitorUid
            };
            result = await DoCacheEnrichmentClientSide(clientProfileDetailsEmpSt.ToList(), context,
                        PropertyTypeConst.EmploymentStatus);
            result = result && await DoCacheEnrichmentClientSide(clientProfileDetailsEmpData.ToList(), context,
                         PropertyTypeConst.EmploymentData);
            result = result && await DoCacheEnrichmentClientSide(clientProfileDetailsDoc.ToList(), context,
                         PropertyTypeConst.Document);
            result = result && await DoCacheEnrichmentClientSide(clientProfileDetailsQuestion.ToList(), context,
                         PropertyTypeConst.Questionnaire);

            _recommendationLogger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LogEntity()
            {

                Class = "UserProcess",
                Function = "SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync",
                Message = "Cache enrichment process completed. BackupRedisKeyAsync(Non Awaitable) process started.",
                LineNumber = UtilityClass.GetLineNumber(),
                Queue = "clientprofilequeue",
                Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
            }));

           _recommendationLogger.Information(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LogEntity()
            {

                Class = "UserProcess",
                Function = "SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync",
                Message = "SaveUserDetailsClientSideAsync method's execution completed.",
                LineNumber = UtilityClass.GetLineNumber(),
                Queue = "clientprofilequeue",
                Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
            }));   
        }


    }
```

Comment: I fail to understand the problem. You wrote: *this method is called recursively or in loop, while there is no such code written to call this function.* and I see a `while(true)` loop that processes queue messages.

Comment: @PeterBons That's correct Peter, I am calling this process in a loop to keep the thread running and fetching new message every time after processing the previous message. But I am also deleting the message from queue after it's processed by ProcessClientProfileQueueMessages method.

You can refer below code block:-
await ProcessClientProfileQueueMessages(message.AsString);
await _clientProfileQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(message);

So ideally in next iteration, same message shouldn't be retrieved, which is processed without any error.